# I want to call a constructor and a method from another class

Tags: java

I am completely lost. I have to Creates a public ledger whose current UTXOPool (collection of unspent transaction outputs) is {@code utxoPool}. This should make a copy of utxoPool by using the UTXOPool(UTXOPool uPool) constructor. My code is pasted below..

```
    public class TxHandler {

    /**
    * Creates a public ledger whose current UTXOPool (collection of unspent        transaction outputs) is
 * {@code utxoPool}. This should make a copy of utxoPool by using the UTXOPool(UTXOPool uPool)
 * constructor.
 */
public TxHandler(UTXOPool utxoPool) {
    // IMPLEMENT THIS
    this.

}

/**
 * @return true if:
 * (1) all outputs claimed by {@code tx} are in the current UTXO pool, 
 * (2) the signatures on each input of {@code tx} are valid, 
 * (3) no UTXO is claimed multiple times by {@code tx},
 * (4) all of {@code tx}s output values are non-negative, and
 * (5) the sum of {@code tx}s input values is greater than or equal to the sum of its output
 *     values; and false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isValidTx(Transaction tx) {
    // IMPLEMENT THIS
}

/**
 * Handles each epoch by receiving an unordered array of proposed transactions, checking each
 * transaction for correctness, returning a mutually valid array of accepted transactions, and
 * updating the current UTXO pool as appropriate.
 */
public Transaction[] handleTxs(Transaction[] possibleTxs) {
    // IMPLEMENT THIS
}
```

}

Comment: What did you try ? What exception you are getting ? Are you getting error during compile time or run time ? Have you find the solution of that exception on Google ?

Comment: You could copy the code [from its GitHub repository](https://github.com/terryyannan/ScroogeCoin/blob/master/TxHandler.java)...

Answer (score 0):

if the other class is placed in an other package, you need to make sure that both your initial class, and the method that you want to call are public, then in the other class you need to import the initial one:

```
import your.original.package.TxHandler;
```

then invoke its methods.

Answer (score 0):

from the instruction - "This should make a copy of utxoPool by using the UTXOPool(UTXOPool uPool) constructor."

so your constructer should be like this

```
public TxHandler(UTXOPool utxoPool) {
// IMPLEMENT THIS
this.utxoPool = new UTXOPool(utxoPool)
```

}